# Does retention.bytes defines the maximum size of inactive segment?

Tags: apache-kafka

i have a kafka setting for retention like this:

```
# A size-based retention policy for logs. Segments are pruned from the log as long as the remaining$
# segments don't drop below log.retention.bytes.$
log.retention.bytes=1073741824$
$
# The maximum size of a log segment file. When this size is reached a new log segment will be created.$
log.segment.bytes=1073741824$
```

So the size of `log.retention.bytes` and `log.segment.bytes` are 1gb, and then i created a topic with only one partition. After flushing message to my topic, i observed that there is alway two log files, one file already reached 1gb and another one is an active one which is receiving messages.

My question is, does this `log.retention.bytes` defines the maximum total size of inactive segments files and not including the active one?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Yes that's roughly correct. I usually don't like to define this setting as the "maximum size" as it's not completely right.

One way to see it is to consider `log.retention.bytes` the minimum amount of data that must be left after Kafka deletes segments. Or the amount of data Kafka guarantees to keep at anytime (obviously only if the time retention limit is not reached!)

The active segment is not eligible for deletion. So as you noticed when the first segment fills up, Kafka does not delete anything even though you reached 1GB. Instead it rolled a new segment (the new active one). Once this new segment also reaches 1GB, you effectively have 2GB of data on disk.

At that point a new segment is rolled again and you have 2 inactive segments. Only now Kafka can delete a segment and still satisfy `log.retention.bytes`, as there will be 1GB of data on disk + the active segment.

Comment: Thanks for answering! It's a little confusing when i first saw this setting, compare to actual disk usage of kafka log file.